# ios5 nested json parse

Tags: iphone, json, parsing, ios5, nsjsonserialization

how do I convert this json with NSJSONSerialization?

```
{
   "messages":{
      "message":{
         "user":"value",
         "pass":"value",
         "url":"value"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it already is JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *dit = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
if (!error) {
   //Get values from this dict using respective keys
   NSDictionary *msgs = [dict objectForKey:@"messages"];
   NSDictionary *msg = [msgs objectForKey:@"message"];
   NSString *user = [msg objectForKey:@"user"];
   NSString *pass = [msg objectForKey:@"pass"];
   NSString *url = [msg objectForKey:@"url"];
}
else {
   //Your error message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example with the new literal syntax:

```
char *jsonChars = "{\
    \"messages\":{\
        \"message\":{\
            \"user\":\"value\",\
            \"pass\":\"value\",\
            \"url\":\"value\"\
        }\
    }\
}";

NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithBytes:jsonChars length:strlen(jsonChars)];
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *dit = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSLog(@"dit: %@", dit);
NSLog(@"dit: messages:message:user = %@", dit[@"messages"][@"message"][@"user"]);
```

NSLog output:

> dit: {
>           messages = {
>               message = {
>                   pass = value;
>                   url = value;
>                   user = value;
>               };
>           };
>       }
>
> dit: messages:message:user = value